# get pointer of functions for use on other fuctions

Tags: c, function, pointers

I need help

I want to return a string in a function and use on another where do I do this?

```
char *randString() {
    int n =  (0 + rand() % ( 4 - 0 ));
    char cadena[5][100] ={
        {"Duck"},
        {"Taxi"},
        {"Hola Mundo!"},
        {"Paris"},
        {"Lexugon"}
    };
    return cadena[n] ;
}
```

and I want to get on main function and send to another function for user...

```
int main (){
    srand(time(NULL));

    int contador = 0;
    /*while (  contador < 100 ){
        char* ptr = randString();
        printf ( "%s\n", ptr );

        contador++;
    }*/
    char *ptr=randString();
    compare( ptr );

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*i want to return a string*" but you are just returning a pointer to a "string", that is `char *` and this pointer refers to memory (`cadena`) local to `randString()` which is gone when being returned from `randString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a string that comes from a local array in the automatic storage, but you could do it if you declared the array `static` and/or moved its declaration to the outer scope:

```
static char cadena[5][100] ={
    {"Duck"},
    {"Taxi"},
    {"Hola Mundo!"},
    {"Paris"},
    {"Lexugon"}
};

char *randString() {
    return cadena[rand() % 5] ;
}
```

You are not allowed to reference variables in automatic storage area when they go out of scope; that would be undefined behavior. Objects in static storage remain valid.

Declaring `cadena` static in the outer scope ensures that the name would remain "invisible" from other translation units, ensuring that a declaration of another `cadena` in a different C file would not create a name collision.

Comment: Declaring the array and it's entries `const` might also make sense.

Comment: @alk, I have no idea what the OP is doing with the returned string. Yes, your suggestion makes sense to me. The function itself could return `char const*` to protect the data from calling functions.

Comment: @causeofhell You are welcome! If you are not looking for further help with this question, consider accepting one of the answers by clicking the grey check mark next to it, to let other site visitors know that your problem is solved, and to earn yourself a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** for this to work with other functions in main, you would have to instead pass a char[] from main to randString function and change it, then return void as the string has already been changed.

***FINAL SOLUTION***

*In Main:*

```
int sizeOfCadena = ;//number of Strings to generate.
char cadena[5][100] = {
    {"Duck"},
    {"Taxi"},
    {"Hola Mundo!"},
    {"Paris"},
    {"Lexugon"}
};
```

- DELETE RandString and replace with:*

  ```
  char *result = cadena[(rand() % 5)];
  ```

Comment: @alk - that is what EDIT was for: I realized the error in my code. I had already fixed it seconds after posting and you waited minutes to downvote me...

Comment: "*yet you are returning a type char*" no, the code does return a `char*` as `cadena` is defined `char[x][y]`.

Comment: @alk - there, fixed, my bad - You are right... Please remove downvote

Comment: @alk - thanks :) for both calling my ass out when I'm wrong and for being chill and removing dv after I fix it

Comment: This isn't wrong anymore, but to my understanding does not really answer the OP's question, as the use case is to have only **one** string in `main()`, not an array as per your proposal.

Comment: @alk - ah yes, the flaws in not reading the full purpose of the program, and just the errors xD. I guess you would create the entire array in main, and simply **char *result = cadena[(rand() % 5)];** instead of a whole function to accomplish just that

Comment: xD wow so many little typing errors today... really oughta be ashamed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
char cadena[5][100] ={ ...
```

use a `static` function variable.

```
static char cadena[5][100] ={ ...
```

Also use of:

```
int n =  (0 + rand() % ( 4 - 0 ));
```

will never return the 5-th element of the array. If you want to include it, use

```
int n =  (rand() % 5);
```

Comment: Declaring the array and it's entries `const` might also make sense.